# Open windows folder from custom button or link

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am trying  to open a windows folder like my computer or my documents or a network folder using a custom button or custom link of an object in salesforce. i.e by clicking that button or link a windows folder should be opened. The folder should be opened with windows explorer not in any browser.How to solve this issues.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot launch a computer application from a website directly. I do know that some versions of Internet Explorer allow a normal hard drive reference to open Explorer (such as specifying file:///C|/Users/Administrator/). Firefox tends to take the route of rendering such links as if they were FTP listings (so it won't open an Explorer window, but this can be changed by a user). Feel free to create a link like above, but just realize that it likely will not work on most systems, nor should it, since that is a potential security risk.